# Dropdown menu in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Ive checked many similar questions but none of them has a working solution in my case.

I'm trying to make a dropdown selection for my user registration form using spring form:select tag. In my bean, country is set as ManyToOne so I pass a map for selecting the value.

Im bouncing between: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'register' available as request attribute. And: commandName not found blabla...

Help me understand what is going on and how to fix it.
It migth be interesting to know that I'm mounting my views through a MergedOutputModel (uses two redirects to mount the view), hence the Session variables.

Code below(simplified to where the problem is appearing).

Controller class:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class RegisterController {
@Autowired
    public CountryDao cDao;

    @RequestMapping("register")
    public String register(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        session.setAttribute("countryList", cDao.getCountryMap());
        return "login/registerForm";
    }}
```

View:

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <spring:message code="register.message" />
    </h1>
    [...]
    <form:form action="addUser" commandName="register" method="post">

        [...]
        <spring:message code="register.country" />
        <form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
        [...]
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code='register.submit'/>" />
    </form:form>
</body>
```

Comment: Two things that I could notice are:  @RequestMapping("/register", method = RequestMethod.POST) and public @ResponseBody String register()

Comment: Where does that fit?

Comment: @RequestMapping("/register", method = RequestMethod.POST) instead of  @RequestMapping("register").....public @ResponseBody String register(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, HttpSession session)  instead of public String register(Model model, @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, HttpSession session). Also one more thing: is the input parameter user to be received as a JSON?

Comment: No JSON. One thing that is missing is the fact that stuff has to survive for two redirects (render merged model) so Models are dying midway it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer to what you need.  Your flow could be slightly different, so you can adjust the page names as needed.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("countryList") //add whatever session attributes as needed
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping("/registerForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registerGet(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", myUserService.createUser());
        model.addAttribute("countryList", countryDao.getCountryMap());
        return "login/registerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/registerVerify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerPost(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
                               Errors result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            FormValidationLogger.log(log, result);
            return "login/registerForm";
        }
        //persist, send emails, or do whatever
        return "registerVerify"; //or whatever page
    }

    @Autowired
    private CountryDao countryDao; //put these at the bottom so we don't have to scroll as much to get to the meat of the code

}
```

I don't readily see the need for `@Transactional` in the code you posted.  I would expect that in your service or DAO layer.

```
<body>
    <h1>
        <spring:message code="register.message" />
    </h1>
    [...]
    <form:form modelAttribute="user" action="/registerVerify" method="post">

        [...]
        <spring:message code="register.country" />
        <form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
        [...]
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code='register.submit'/>" />
    </form:form>
</body>
```

This assumes that `country` is a property of `user`.  You also may want to change the method name to something like `getCountries()` instead of `getCountryMap()`.

Comment: Ok, I see a nice code reordering here. I'll test it but there are still some questions that persist. Will this survive a redirect? When I declare countrylist as session attribute, will it wire the attribute thats declared inside my method? Also, CountryMap is a ManyToOne attribute in user. Im using a map to create a dropdown, hence getCountryMap. Shouldn`t I do it?

Comment: Now getting **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute**. Even tried to add user as session variable. Man, this thing makes no sense to me.